# How to convert Response.ok().build() to json type

Tags: java, json

I  am making a request to an API and getting a response status code of 200.

Response of the api doesnot include a json response.

```
@POST method
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
return Response.ok().build();
```

How can I convert the response as JSON ?

Answer (score 3):

```
@Produces("application/json")
public Response foo(){
(...)
    return Response.ok(yourEntity).build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to specify that your method is returning the json file using the annotation

```
@Produces("application/json")
```

see this tutorial for more reference

[https://www.javatpoint.com/jax-rs-file-download-example]